# Writing void pointer to binary file

Tags: c++, pointers, binaryfiles

I'm trying to write and read `VlGMM` from VLFeat to a binary file, in particular its component `void *means`. You can find the class code [here](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/vl/gmm.c).

This is the 2 functions that I've written:

```
void writeVlGMM(const std::string &name, VlGMM* gmm){
        std::ofstream out(name,std::ios_base::binary);
        const void *means = vl_gmm_get_means(gmm); //dimension*numComponents elements
        out.write((char *) &means, sizeof(means));
        for(int i=0;i<dimension*numComponents;i++)
            std::cout<<*((float*)(means)+i)<<" ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
void readVlGMM(vl_type dataType, const std::string &name, VlGMM* gmm, vl_size dimension, vl_size numComponents){
        std::ifstream in( name, std::ios::binary );
        vl_size size = vl_get_type_size(dataType) ;
        void *means = vl_calloc (numComponents * dimension, size) ;
        in.read((char *) &means, sizeof(means));
    }
```

If I try to print `means` values in both functions through this code (notice that I know that means is filled with floating points):

```
    for(int i=0;i<dimension*numComponents;i++)
        std::cout<<*((float*)(means)+i)<<" ";
```

The printed values are the same **in the same program execution**, so I guess that the code above works. Anyway, I think that what I'm writing in the file is the pointer value, not the `mean's` value themselves! Is it possible that in different program executions the code above is not going to work?

This is because when the program execution terminates `gmm` is deallocated and so `means`, and the saved pointer is meaningless.

Is this correct? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: 1. cannot (not make sense) write void pointer, has sense write content pointed by this pointer. Subject is wrong

Comment: @JacekCz: If you mean writing `void *` to a file does not make sense, you are correct (unless this is some debugging/tracing file). Apparently OP tries to write a `float` to the file, but that still is not clear.

Comment: Lookup _de-/serialization_

Comment: Define a **proper and clean** file-format **first**. Then start serialising/marshalling the dat to/from that file. As you use C++, not C (don't spam tags!), don't use `void *`, but an interface for the types you want to store/load.

Comment: THen: This is no code review or "check my code" site. See [ask], state your **specific problem** along with a [mcve].

Comment: a pointer only has meaning in that specific computer. Copying it to file is pointless as you can't read that again anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible that in different program executions the code above is not going to work?

Yes, it's about as possible as `1+1==2`.

> Is this correct?

Absolutely.

> How can I solve the problem?

Write and read the array rather than its address:

```
vl_size size = vl_get_type_size(dataType);
const void *means = vl_gmm_get_means(gmm)
out.write(static_cast<const char*>(means), numComponents * dimension * size);

/// ...

vl_size size = vl_get_type_size(dataType);
void *means = vl_calloc (numComponents * dimension, size) ;
in.read(static_cast<char*>(means), numComponents * dimension * size);
```

Comment: In addition to writing the float values to the file, the code should first write the count of entries to the file, and then when reading, verify that the number written is the number being read.

Comment: @RossBencina yes that would be an obvious improvement.

Comment: Also, the given code in this answer assumes that the reading and writing programs have the same byte-order/endianness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that `(char *)` is necessary in both operation, right?

Comment: @RossBencina Yes, exactly. This is a reasonable assumption, given that OP tries to run the same binary program in both cases.

Comment: @justHelloWorld just fixed it.